# Why is my jquery json each() loop returning undefined?

Tags: jquery, json

Here is my local Json which is validating in Jsonlint.

```
{
"messages": {
    "count": "0",
    "items": [
        {
            "MessageID": "1",
            "Starred": 0,
            "BodyPrev": "You wouldn't believe what has just happenedYou wouldn't believe what has ",
            "FromUserID": "1",
            "FromName": "Daisy Purdye",
            "FromUN": "daisypurdye",
            "Subject": "Yeayeah",
            "Body": "You wouldn't believe what has just happenedYou wouldn't believe what has just happenedYou wouldn't believe what has just happenedYou wouldn't believe what has just happenedYou wouldn't believe what has just happenedYou wouldn't believe what has just happened",
            "Ctime": "10/4/2012",
            "isRead": "1"
        },
        {
            "MessageID": "2",
            "Starred": 1,
            "BodyPrev": "Whatever",
            "FromUserID": "1",
            "FromName": "Daisy Purdye",
            "FromUN": "daisypurdye",
            "Subject": "Not true mate",
            "Body": "Whatever",
            "Ctime": "5/3/2012",
            "isRead": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

and here is the jQuery to print out the messages...

```
    <script>
    $.getJSON("/json/messages.json",function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, messages){
            console.log(messages.items.Subject)
        });
      });
   </script>
```

It is just returning undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.each` should receive an array and you pass it the root object, which isn't an array, as your array of messages is in `result.messages.items`.

To iterate over the messages, you should do

```
  $.getJSON("/json/messages.json",function(result){
    $.each(result.messages.items, function(i, message){
        console.log(message.Subject)
    });
  });
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. This was one of those problems my tired mind could have looked at it all day long and still not seen the obvious :D this makes perfect sense. Ill accept the answer in a few mins when I'm allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Items is itself an array so im guessing you need to at least access it like:

```
messages.items[0].Subject
```

Answer (score 0):

items is an array. you should iterate through  it to get all items.

```
 <script>
    $.getJSON("/json/messages.json",function(result){
        $.each(result, function(i, messages){
          $.each(messages.items, function(index, item){
                 console.log(item.Subject)
           });

        });
      });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `items` property is an array, so you can't use `items.Subject`.

Loop through the items in the array, instead of looping through the properties in the root object:

```
$.getJSON("/json/messages.json",function(result){
  $.each(result.messages.items, function(i, item){
    console.log(item.Subject)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the logic. Try this:

```
<script>
        $.getJSON("/json/messages.json",function(result){
            $.each(result.items, function(i, item){
                console.log(item.Subject)
            });
          });
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your object exist in this form

```
MainObj---> messages -----> items---->Subject
```

so if you need to print the subject then you have to access in the same manner as they exist

```
result.messages.items.Subject
```